# I am trying to sum values with jQuery and display that value in an HTML tag

Tags: jquery

So i am trying to do some addition and display the sum based on what my end user selects from a group of 3 check boxes.
I am using some hidden fields to bring my values into the form, and doing a sum on the 3 hidden fields that contain the price. That value is visible within the console, but i cannot get it to show up in the id where I cab display to the end users.
My html form:

```
<div class="content-1 p-3">
<img src="img/upsell-3-image-3.png" alt="img" class="title">
<div class="row">
    <p>
        <strong>Select a scent</strong>
        <label><input class="check-box" id="product_1" name="product" checked = "checked" type="checkbox" value="611">611 Description</label><br/><br/>
        <label><input class="check-box" id="product_2" name="product" type="checkbox" value="612">612 Description</label><br/><br/>
        <label><input class="check-box" id="product_3" name="product" type="checkbox" value="614">614 Description</label>
    </p>
    <span id="total"></span>
</div>
<div class="cta">
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" id="upsell" >
        <input type='hidden' name='upsell_step' value='3' id="upsell_step">
        <input type='hidden' id='611' name='611' value='1' />
        <input type='hidden' id='612' name='612' value='0' />
        <input type='text' id='614' name='614' value='0' />
        <input type='text' id='total' name='total' value='0' />
        <input type='hidden' id='611_price' name='611_price' value='29.99' />
        <input type='hidden' id='612_price' name='612_price' value='0' />
        <input type='text' id='614_price' name='614_price' value='0' />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="do_ajax();"><img src="img/btn-3.png" width="449" height="87" alt="" /></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

My scripting:

```
<script>
var firstFlag = 1;
var secondFlag = 0;
var thirdFlag = 0;
var sum = 0;
    $("#product_1").click(function(){
        if(firstFlag == 0){
            Second611(); firstFlag = 1;
        }else{
            first611(); firstFlag = 0;
        }
    });
    function first611(){
        $("#611").val('0');
        $("#611_price").val('0.00');
    }
    function Second611(){
        $("#611").val('1');
        $("#611_price").val('19.99');
    }
    $("#product_2").click(function(){
        if( secondFlag == 1){
            second612(); secondFlag = 0;
        } else {
            first612(); secondFlag = 1;
        }
    });
    function first612(){        
        $("#612").val('1');
        $("#612_price").val('19.99');
    }
    function second612(){
        $("#612").val('0');
        $("#612_price").val('0.00');
    }
    $("#product_3").click(function(){
        if( thirdFlag == 1){
            second614(); thirdFlag = 0;
        } else {
            first614(); thirdFlag = 1;
        }
    });
    function first614(){
        $("#614").val('1');
        $("#614_price").val('9.99');
    }
    function second614(){
        $("#614").val('0');
        $("#614_price").val('0.00');
    }

    $("input[name=product]").change(function() {
        console.log ("change");
        var sum = parseFloat($("#611_price").val()) + parseFloat($("#612_price").val()) + parseFloat($("#614_price").val());
        console.log (sum);
        $("#total").html(sum);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#pop_overlay').css('display','none');
    });
    function do_ajax() {
        $('#pop_overlay').fadeIn(300);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'includes/upsell.php', 
            data: $('#upsell').serialize(), 
            success: function (response) {
                var res = response.split("|");
                $('#pop_overlay').fadeOut(300);
                if ($.trim(res[0]) == "ok") {
                    window.location.href = 'thankyou.php' + res[1];
                } else {
                    alert(res[0]);
                }
            }
            , error: function (a, b, c) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

i am trying to get this "$("#total").html(sum); " to show up here "" or here ""

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that you have an error in your HTML. The ID attribute must be unique. You have multiple elements with id="total", here

```
<span id="total"></span>
```

and here

```
<input type='text' id='total' name='total' value='0' />
```

The selector

```
$("#total")
```

Is returning the first matching element as per this statement in the jquery docs:

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

Actually I would expect the first matched element to be the span in pure sequence in the html terms. Maybe add this console.log() after your current one to confirm.

console.log("The real Spartacas element is " + $("#total").get(0).outerHTML)

Assuming you are getting the input with id="total" then the input element does not have an html() function.

Finally, after you fix the id issue, you can use .text() on the intended span element to set the value since there is no html markup involved in the string you want it to hold.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have removed the text box with the id of total, so now i only have the span tag left.

the console is logging 
"The real Spartacas element is <span id="total"></span>" when i select a checkbox, so that is where the total is being told to go, but i am still getting no value displayed.

I have also changed the the command that fills the id to .text "$("#total").text(sum);"

Comment: I was mistaken, further up in my page I had another span tag with the id of total.  Thank you for bringing the obvious into the light. I appreciate it

Comment: @David - aha, that is one of the issues with posting a sample of the page. Anyway glad to have got you on the right path. If you found my answer useful please could you vote it up or better still tick it to indicate it was the correct answer. Thx.